# Pulling PowerPoint Text Attributes Through Python

Tags: python, powerpoint

I am trying to pull in the attributes associated with my text in PowerPoint and am getting weird outputs... The output from shape.fill is not as expected. I am also curious to find the other attributes like shape.font and the position of the shape - is this possible?

Issue:

```
f = shape.fill
Output: <pptx.dml.fill.FillFormat object at 0x00000215C4D6DD90>
```

Code:

```
mylist = []
mylist2 = []
mylist3 = []
mylist4 = []
mylist5 = []
mylist6 = []
mylist7 = []

for eachfile in glob.glob(direct):
    s = 1
    file = os.path.basename(eachfile)
    try:
        prs = Presentation(eachfile)
        for slide in prs.slides:
            for shape in slide.shapes:
                if hasattr(shape, "text"):            
                    x = nltk.word_tokenize(shape.text)
                    t = shape.text
                    f = shape.fill
                    print(f)
                    mylist4.append(file)
                    mylist5.append(t)
                    mylist7.append(f)
                    mylist6.append('Slide: ' + str(s))
    #                x = shape.text.split() #looks for words with punctuation included
                    for word in x:
                        word = word.lower()
                        if word in terms:
                            mylist.append("Slide " + str(s))
                            mylist2.append(file)
                            mylist3.append(word)

            s = s + 1
    except:
        pass

#mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
d = {'FileName':mylist2,'Slide':mylist, 'Match':mylist3}
d2 = {'FileName':mylist4, 'Slide':mylist6, 'Text':mylist5, 'Color':mylist7}
search = phrases + terms
d3 = {'Text':search}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

`<pptx.dml.fill.FillFormat object at 0x00000215C4D6DD90>` is a python object. You need to look up the documentation for these type of objects and use its attribute functions in order to get information out of it.

The only documentation I could find for this type of object is [this one](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pptx/dml/fill.html), although that is not a "normal" one, but just the source code. Functions You can use are written inside of the `FillFormat` class, starting with `back_color(self, ...)`

Comment: So based on this, would I just need to add ._fill.back_color to the f = shape._fill ? I'm assuming its more complicated than taht

Comment: You could go ahead and try out all possibilities in a python console. Import Your module and get the object for one specific slide that you know. Then play around with the object methods and see what you get. If you face a `<... object at ...>` again, that's a python object - just google it by the displayed name and look up the docs.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation describes what you should expect on any given attribute. For example, here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/dml.html#fillformat-objects
you can find out how to interrogate the `FillFormat` object that `Shape.fill` returns.

In many cases, things are substantially more complex than the common cases and the API will reflect that. For example, fills come in several varieties: an RGB color (most common), a pattern (repeated bitmap mask), an image (either tiled or fit in a variety of ways), and a "null" fill. Accommodating all these options requires you to learn more about PowerPoint than you probably originally wanted to know :)

The overall API documentation is here: https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#api-documentation

Comment: So if I just wanted the color, is that a simple addition or no? Why is grabbing the text from the shape easy but the color not so much?